# Am I computing this complex root correctly?

Tags: polynomials, roots, complex-analysis

I'm playing numerically with root-finding in Matlab but am a bit rusty with complex roots that come in conjugate pairs -- for polynomials with real coefficients.

Am I justifying these steps correctly:

$$x^2 + 4 = 0$$

$$=> x^2 = -4$$

$$=> |x| = \sqrt{( 4 * (-1) )} = 2 i $$

$$ x =
\begin{cases}
2i,  & \text{for x > 0} \\
-2i, & \text{for x < 0}
\end{cases}
$$

I feel like I'm mixing up the real and the complex definitions of the absolute value / modulus function.

Comment: I see no numerics, this should be on Math.se (or just read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). You are giving a definition of $x$ that depends on $x$....

Comment: @David nevermind, I used the quadratic formula

Comment: You need to drop the absolute-values on the left hand side of the last formula.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth true true, thanks dog